# Embedding Blazor web pages in .NET Core library to serve in a ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I've been creating libraries from features that I've been using across multiple projects. For instance, I have an authentication library that has all functionality needed to manage users, logging in, access control, and so on. Everything related to authentication/authorization is in there, like models, services, and controllers.

Then I just add this library to the other projects that need authentication and ASP.NET recognizes the controllers inside the library and everything works great.

Now I want to do the same with my analytics code. I have already put it in the library, but in this case, I would like to have some dashboard pages in the library.

These libraries are meant to be used on API projects. What I want to do is something like what Swagger does, the user installs the analytics library and he would have access to a dashboard route to see the usage statistics.

Would I be able to do something like this with Blazor? Create the pages and components inside my library and expose them to a route in the API that uses the library?

I see that Blazor apps are in a totally different template, for this reason I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

-- UPDATE --

I managed to add a Blazor application to the solution and reference it to an API project.

With this configuration my API is able to show the Blazor app in the `/index.html` path:

```
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

        ...

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
```

The problem is that the Blazor application is not a dll, and does not generate a nuget package. If I change the Blazor application output type to `Library` then the `/index.html` route does not work anymore.

Comment: This could do with a few concrete examples. Also, what part of ASP.NET do you refer to? MVC? Razor?

Comment: I updated my question with what I get so far, but I would like to use Blazor if possible.